# Small Signal Model of Two-Switch Forward - Basso

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, ltspice, small-signal, forward

I've designed a two-switch forward converter, that I would like to create a small signal model for to examine the stability criteria of the converter and then compatibility with the EMI filter...

A transient simulation was created, and the supply works great. I attempted to create the small signal model using Christophe Basso's available PWM-CM models, but am struggling to produce a proper Bode plot or make sense of my simulation... Changing the type-II compensator values does not change the Bode plot...

*Using LTSpice because it's the only available and downloadable software where I am.*

Any advice or recommendations? Am I using the PWM-CM, Gain, XFMR or Ampsimp model wrong?

[image: Circuit Schematic]

[image: Circuit Schematic1]

[image: Bode Plot]

**Additional**

[image: DC Schematic]
[image: DC sim]

Comment: @VerbalKint calling verbalkint, this one's for you.

Comment: Hi there, have a look at this [PDF](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Forward%20small-signal.pdf) and check the schematics I provided for the forward converter. Also, you have several examples of forward converters in my [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) which work on the free demo version of SIMPLIS. It's easy to run and you will then be able to check your LTspice results versus those obtained with SIMPLIS.

Comment: I recommend you also look at this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544507/small-signal-forward-converter) I gave a while ago. In your sim, try first to *physically* open the loop by biasing the modulator input with a dc+ac source (forget the loop in a first approach) and check a) the operating point, a correct output and duty ratio then b) the ac response. When this looks correct, you can start considering closing the loop.

Comment: As always @VerbalKint, the god of control, answers the calling and arrives at the speed of light. Even God doesn't answer my prayers that quickly.

Comment: @VerbalKint I opened the loop and injected an AC(1) signal into the input along with the 28VDC. The output is not biasing to the designed +5.3V. My nominal duty cycle is calculated to be 37.3% - I connected a voltage source to the Vctrl pin similar to your PDF example. Edited post to include visual image of schematic and plots for the DC operation. Thanks.

Comment: For a 5-V/5-A forward converter operated from a 28-V source, rough-cut calculations show a sense resistance of 200 m\$\Omega\$ and not 20 as I seem to read in your parameter list. Can you please check this? Thanks.

Comment: @VerbalKint I should clarify that I'm using a current sense XFMR :) which is sensing the high side FET. 1.5k burden resistor -> diode -> Rsense -> RC filter if that makes sense. XFMR has turns ratio of (Npri=1:Nsec=60). So I guess the CS gain is really Rsense (20 Ohms ) * (1/60) = 0.333

Comment: You should pass the *equivalent* sense resistance as a parameter to the model, it is important. Besides, the bias voltage to the CM model input is not the duty ratio but the voltage setpoint for an expected peak current. For instance, if the sense resistance is 0.5 \$\Omega\$ and you need a 3-A peak current, then the voltage to apply is 1.5 V.

Comment: @VerbalKint Good morning Mr. Basso, could you please review the following schematic and plots? [1, Schematic - https://i.imgur.com/ywqjqVc.png], [2, Transient Sim (+5.3V) - https://i.imgur.com/1kFH9L8.png], [3, AC injection - https://i.imgur.com/QHEgtT7.png] and [4, Bode plot - https://i.imgur.com/opHp3wc.png]... Am I implementing the PWM model correctly now and using the correct parameters? The bode plots seem to look good, but when I change my type-II compensator values, the phase and gain do not change at all! Any idea why? Thanks!... *edit: PWM is UC1845*

Comment: @VerbalKint Additional plot of transient sim with AC(1) also injected at input https://i.imgur.com/KJ4bRDG.png - wave forms seem to match up (except Vcomp marked as Vb) and DC is reading 36% nom duty cycle as calculated... Bode plot still not changing after changing compensator values.

Comment: @user397703, hello, I don't understand why the observation of the output goes through a long chain of sources and generator before reaching the compensator? I would advise to first get rid of these extra sources, then run the simulations and compensate the converter. Please remember to reduce the LoL/CoL network to 1p or so for transient runs as you want the loop to be closed in this mode. The compensator is inactive because you drive the (-) pin from a low impedance why all design formulas imply you bias the (-) pin from a resistive divider.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thanks for getting back to me. Instead of using a resistor divider for the feedback into error amp, I was trying to use a differential amplifier --> buffer --> external error amplifier (overriding internal UC1845 error amp)... I can confirm that my compensator is changing with value after removing the differential amp and buffer... I guess I will exclude them for the sim... Do I also measure the loop-gain of a power supply also by simply probing the output? or should should it be Vctrl/Vset (Vset is output node after LoL/CoL filter if that makes sense?)

Comment: @user397703 - Hi, For the 2nd time, you have deleted important information from the question. When you post a question, you grant an *irrevocable* license for Stack Exchange to use and publish what you included (see the "Legal" link at the bottom of the page, in the section under "Subscriber Content"). In short, it's too late to delete it now - especially since those images are *required* for your question to make sense for future readers. Therefore I have reverted (rolled-back) your edit. Please do not change the question again. Thanks.

Comment: @user397703 - As you again edited the question to vandalise it and remove the images, despite my previous comment, the question has now been reverted to its previous state, then locked and cannot now be edited, except by a moderator or SE staff.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at a simple simulation setup with my auto-toggling CCM-DCM current-mode model that I introduced in 2005 at a [PCIM conference](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Divers/PCIM%202005.pdf). The original structure is based on the work carried by Vatché Vorpérian in 1990 where he presented his concept of the PWM switch adapted to current mode. This model is a beauty of simplicity and I encourage you to read his paper that you can download from [here](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Papers/Analysis%20of%20CM%20Controlled%20PWM%20Converters.pdf). This model perfectly agrees with the work carried by Ray Ridley in which he used sampled-data analysis while Vatché only resorted to time-continuous expressions. In the end, the transfer functions obtained with either approaches are identical.

Vorpérian looked at the continuous conduction mode (CCM) but did not publish his approach for the DCM. That is what I looked at and I crafted a fully auto-toggling model capable of predicting sub-harmonic oscillations in CCM and buck instability in DCM in certain conditions. So this model is fairly versatile and has been ported to LTspice and other SPICE simulators. You can easily simulate a converter based on the UC384x PWM controller. What is specific to the UC384x is the fact the error voltage delivered by the on-board op-amp first goes through two diodes in series and then undergoes a division by 3 before being clamped to 1 V: in case of loop failure, the maximum current setpoint is then 1 V/\$R_{sense}\$. The two-diode drop is there to impose a true zero setpoint when the op-amp falls below 1.2 V roughly and the UC384x can actually skip cycle by going to 0% duty ratio in no-load conditions.

The below figure shows how to assemble the model to simulate a forward converter. In this approach, the transformer is placed after the input source and effectively translates the buck voltage to \$NV_{in}\$ but it could also be placed after the PWM switch model also. Both options are explored in my last [book](https://stairwaypress.com/product/transfer-functions-of-switching-converters/) on transfer functions:

[image]

To clamp the voltage at the CM PWM switch model, many options are possible and I used an in-line expression clamping the error voltage while performing the \$2V_f\$ subtraction and the division by 3. The type 2 is automated and please note that components values depend on the upper resistance \$R_{upper}\$ only as \$R_{lower}\$ is silent considering the virtual ground at the (-) pin. Once the ac analysis is run, *always* check the operating points to verify voltages are on par with what is expected: a duty ratio of 32.6% for this particular point, a 5-V output voltage, a credible output level for the op-amp etc. From there, you can display the ac response of the power stage and feed the macro with the magnitude/phase values collected at the selected crossover of 10 kHz:

[image]

Check that the compensated loop gain meets the phase/gain margins criteria but it looks good here. Of course, from there, you would need to run many more simulations like Monte Carlo to check that despite components tolerances, various input and output conditions etc. the phase/gain margins and crossover always guaranty a reliable operation.

When this is working, you can perform a transient simulation:

[image]

In this example, I have used IsSpice from Intusoft but you should obtain identical results from LTspice. I don't know what model version do you use for the PWM CM model though and I know there are plenty of versions (I posted a few on my [page](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm)). As I said in the comments section, I don't use SPICE anymore and I prefer using SIMPLIS as I can immediately extract the ac response from the switching circuit without the need to resort to an average model. It offers the advantage of simplicity but it also works for converters who do not have an averaged model like the LLC converter for instance. Finally, I used SIMPLIS a lot to verify my equation-based models published in my last book. You can find plenty of [ready-made examples](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) working on the free demo Elements and there are forward converters if you want to give it a try. I hope this is useful for your design! Cheers.